# Strange tree conflicts with SVN 1.7 reintegrate merge

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I've recently joined a new team that is using SVN 1.7.5 and they tend to handle their branching and merging slightly differently than I.  I always follow this pattern:

1. Branch from trunk
2. Merge trunk to branch as needed
3. Final merge of trunk to branch
4. --reintegrate merge of branch to trunk
5. Delete branch

For some reason, they're convinced that you should *never* merge trunk to your branch after the initial copy.  Instead, they just merge the branch back to trunk when finished and resolve all their conflicts there.  I'm not sure if they do a regular merge or --reintegrate merge.  They also do some funky things where they merge stuff from unrelated proof-of-concept branches directly into trunk, and have multiple "trunks" (I'm not positive if that's anything more than a long-lived branch that's placed alongside trunk instead of the branches directory).

The problem I'm up against is that whenever I handle branching and merging the way I'm used to (which I believe is generally considered to be the "correct" way), I get tons of tree conflicts when reintegrating a feature branch.  One example I've got right now is with several files that originated on a proof-of-concept branch that was merged into trunk and, subsequently, into my feature branch.  I haven't touched the files but reintegrating gives me "local add, incoming add upon merge" for some (but not all) of them.

Another person on the team decided to give it a try too and merged trunk to his feature branch just before a reintegrate.  In his case, he got *tons* of tree conflicts, one of which was on a file that was added directly to trunk and never modified on any branch.  He solved it by rolling his branch back to the revision prior to where he pulled in trunk and doing the reintegrate like everyone else does.

Is it possible that there's something in our repository that has been corrupted?  Could the branching scheme that everyone else is using cause SVN to get confused?  Is there anything I can do to repair whatever's wrong?

Comment: Is SVN 1.7 used on the client as well as on the server? Has the repository been upgraded to current format? If the repository has been created with an older version, you have to use `svnadmin upgrade` in order to use merge tracking. Do the sub-directiories in the trunk have different values for `svn:mergeinfo`?

Comment: I haven't asked around, but I'd be shocked if anyone was using a pre-1.7 client.  The repository was only created a few months ago so I believe it's been 1.7 the whole time.  However, I think this used to be in Git and someone decided they liked SVN better.  Could the Git->SVN conversion have created bad mergeinfo?

Comment: I'm not sure how to tell if the sub-directories of trunk have different mergeinfo.  If I do `svn propget svn:mergeinfo ^/trunk`, `svn propget svn:mergeinfo -R ^/trunk`, or either of those using a working copy path instead, I just get the same list of all the branches and nothing that starts with trunk.

Comment: Just use `svn propget -R svn:mergeinfo ^/`. The command should output only the top level branch and trunk directories. If it prints any sub-directories, that might be a reason for the merge conflicts.

Comment: I'm in an almost identical boat. Your workflow is correct by my knowledge as well, and I don't remember getting these tree conflicts before, but I've been using git and hg for the last 5 years or so.  I know that when the "local and incoming" actions are the same, in this case "add/add upon merge", it's pretty safe to just 'resolve --accept working'.  We also have half our team using cmdline and the other half using tortoise, so I'm still pinning down the problem.  I'll write up an answer if I find out the source.